# Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

What if I wanted to track anytime someone clicks on the same telephone number anywhere on my web site? And where exactly would I put the code? I know, you can use this code for example to track one instance:

```
<a href="tel:18285053969" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click/Touch', 'Home Banner');">828.505.3969</a>
```

Comment: for some reason it didn't include my code: a href="tel:18285053969" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click/Touch', 'Home Banner');">828.505.3969